# execvp and reading command arguments

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm working on a project in which I have to write a command shell for linux in C.  So far, it's working for commands with no input (ie, the shell will run the 'date' command and 'ls' command fine.)

However, commands which require some input, it seems like it reads each input as a seperate command.  For instance, for the command:

```
% gcc -o testFile testFile.c
```

It seems as if the shell is running gcc as its own command, then -o, then testFile, and testfile.c when it should be taking gcc as the command, with the other three entries as inputs.

I don't understand what's going on in the code - and it probably comes from not understanding the execvp function fully (I read about it from several sources and I still don't think I understand it - I thought I did!).

The execvp call is in the function execute.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "commandStorage.c"

#define MAX_ARGUMENTS 10


void parseLine(char *command, char **args) {

const char split = '\0';
int i;
char *ptrToken;

while(*command != '\0') {
    while ((*command == '\n') || (*command == '\t')
        || (*command == ' ')) {
        *(command++) = '\0';
        } // end 'while'
    *args++ = command;
    printf("%s\n", command);
    while ((*command != '\n') && (*command != '\t')
        && (*command != '\0') && (*command != ' ')) {
        command++;
        } // end 'while'

    } // end 'while'
*args = '\0';
} // end parseLine

void execute(char **arrayOfPtrs) {
/*
CURRENT BUG:
The function is taking the array of pointers, and executing each
input from the array seperately.

The execvp function is being misused.
*/
pid_t pid;
int waitStatus;

switch (pid = fork()) {
    case 0:  // Child process
        if (execvp(arrayOfPtrs[0], arrayOfPtrs) < 0) {
            perror("THE COMMAND FAILED TO EXECUTE!");
            break;

            } // end 'if

    case -1:  // Fork failed
        perror("THE PROCESS FAILED TO FORK");
        break;

    default: // Parent process
        while ((wait(&waitStatus) != pid)) {};
        break;
} // end 'switch'
return;
} // end 'execute

void clearPointerArray(char **args){

while (*args != NULL) {
    *(args++) = NULL;
}
}


int main() {

int i;
char command[MAX_STRING_LENGTH]; // unparsed command
pid_t pid;
char *args[MAX_ARGUMENTS]; // Argument vector.


while(1) {
    clearPointerArray(args);
    printf("%s", "TimsShell--> ");
    scanf("%s", command);

    parseLine(command, args);

    if ((strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0) || (strcmp(args[0], "quit") == 0)) {
        printf("%s\n", "Goodbye!");
        return 0;
    }

    execute(args);

    }// while loop
return 0;

} // main
```

And here is some output from the commandline:

```
% gcc -o mainShell mainShell.c
% ./mainShell
TimsShell--> date
date
Fri Feb 14 15:50:28 EST 2014
TimsShell--> ls
ls
change.log      doLocalConf.xml   license.txt   notepad++.exe  session.xml               testFile.c
commandStorage.c  functionList.xml  localization  plugins     shortcuts.xml         themes
config.model.xml  langs.model.xml   mainShell      readme.txt     stylers.model.xml    updater
config.xml      langs.xml        mainShell.c   SciLexer.dll     stylers.xml          user.manual
TimsShell--> gcc -o testFile testFile.c
gcc
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
TimsShell--> -o
THE COMMAND FAILED TO EXECUTE!: No such file or directory
TimsShell--> testFile
THE COMMAND FAILED TO EXECUTE!: No such file or directory
TimsShell--> testFile.c
: not found 2: testFile.c: 
testFile.c: 3: testFile.c: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
TimsShell--> ^C
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're treating ` `, `\n` and `\t` specially, rather than acting like a real shell would and allowing any character in `IFS` to act as a separator (with `\n\t ` as the default IFS value)? I'd argue that the way you're doing it here actually makes the code harder to follow than the correct behavior would.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the man page for scanf for why this happening. The problem is in your format string:

> %s
>
> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer
>   must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the
>   input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added
>   automatically. The input string stops at white space or at the maximum
>   field width, whichever occurs first.

Try this instead:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", command);
getchar();
```

or

```
scanf(" %[^\n]s", command);
```

Comment: Or even better, use `fgets()`.

Comment: scanf("%[^\n]s", a) doesn't work - it just keeps repeating the command over and over again.

For fgets(), I don't have a file to extract from - I just want to extract the user input.

Comment: @newalchemy: Use `fgets(command, MAX_STRING_LENGTH, stdin);`. The usage of `scanf()` here is unsafe anyway, since you're not putting a limit on the input length, but you're trying to store it all in `command` all the same.

Comment: The reason is because with that format specifier, the '\n' doesn't get consumed. If you're really decided on using scanf, you will have to call 'getchar();' after the scanf function to pull the newline off the input stream.

Comment: I put in the exact fgets command you typed and now its saying all my commands are invalid... I looked at the fgets documentation and I don't see why this could be happening.

Comment: @newalchemy: It works for me, although you need to add a `break;` for your `case 0` in your `execute()` function, right now it only `break`s if `execvp()` fails, and falls through to the `-1` case at all other times. Your `clearPointerArray()` function has broken logic, too, and undefined behavior since you're accessing uninitialized pointer values.

Comment: The reason is that with fgets the newline character will be stored in output string, and parseLine is failing to handle that (it's turning into an empty string argument).